# lazy loading angular 4 module available in different source folder

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, lazy-loading, webpack-2

I am trying to lazy load modules (Angular 4) available in another folder(/home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/**lazy2**/src/app) to the currently running app folder(/home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/**lazy1**/src/app).
To explain the whole scenario, I have an angular 4 app created with angular-cli with a component which can be lazily loaded.

I have two components available here eager and lazy. where the lazy component is configured via angular router to load on demand, this lazy loading setup works fine.
Below is the working routing config:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'eager', component: EagerComponent },
    //   { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
    { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: '/home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy1/src/app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
 ];
```

Now I have copied the same project to another folder(lazy2) and trying to load the component from **lazy2** folder to app available in the **lazy1** folder.

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: '/home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

On doing so I get the error :
*ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol LazyModule in /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts, resolving symbol LazyModule in /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts*

I think there should be some way of achieving this, I know, I am doing something wrong, It will be really great if someone could help me identify the issue.

Link to the github repo for same app:
[lazy-loading-angular4](https://github.com/abskr82/lazy-loading-angular4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your node_modules folder from lazy2. From what I can see, it looks like you've got some conflicts with the @angular/core module used in your lazy2 and lazy1 folders.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for replying,
I did remove node_modules folder from lazy2. And webpack failed to compile with below error:
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @angular/core relative to /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts., resolving symbol LazyModule in /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts, resolving symbol LazyModule in /home/abhishek/programming/angular4/lazy-loading/lazy2/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts

Comment: Then I don't know :/ I don't think it's possible to actually lazy load a module from one Angular app to another like what you're trying to do. If you figure that out, let me know :)

Comment: Sure @Orodan, I'll definitely post if a get this working :)